# UIViewController not presenting from storyboard

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a UIViewController in Main.storyboard and I am trying to present it programmatically from inside an UIImagePickerController delegate method. But I am receiving the message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DAAnalysisViewController: 0x8b99960> on 
<DAViewController: 0x8b35300> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    DAAnalysisViewController *asdf = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] 
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"];

    [self presentViewController:asdf animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How do I properly present a UIViewController from a storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image picker is being presented modally, you may need to dismiss it first and THEN you can display your custom view controller. Something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        DAAnalysisViewController *asdf = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"];

        [self presentViewController:asdf animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was just going through the UIViewController programming guide trying to figure out the problem.